# What app or extension do I need to open a Windows cursor - .cur - file?

Tags: gnome, cursor, image-viewers

I have created a .cur file using an online image editing tool, but I can't open it. Gnome Image Viewer seems to lack some extension that is supposed to allow me to see .cur files. But after doing its search, the Gnome Image Viewer app can't find the required extension. I suppose I should look for it myself and add it manually. What do you advice me to do?

1. Should I search for the extension Gnome Image Viewer app? And, in this case, where should I go, and what are the required steps?
2. Should I use an independent app specially created for Windows cursors? And, in this case, what are, in your opinion the best apps?

Thank you in advance for your advices!

Answer (score 2):

There is a command for that: `icotool` and it is part of [icoutils](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/icoutils/)

> The  icotool program converts and creates icon (.ico) and cursor (.cur)
>      files. At the moment icons can only be created from and extracted  into
>      PNG files. This is done using libpng.
>
> Icon  and  cursor  files  are  used  mainly on the Microsoft Windows(R)
>      platform. Each icons or cursors file may  contain  multiple  images  of
>      various  resolutions  and with different number of colors. Cursor files
>      differ from icon files in that they also contain information about  the
>      hotspot of each image.
>
> Recent  versions  of  Microsoft's Internet Explorer use icons for small
>      site logotypes. The browser fetches a file called  favicon.ico  from  a
>      web  site,  and  uses  the images in this file to represent the site in
>      menus and site lists. (This file is  placed  in  the  web  site's  root
>      directory,  like any other file.) Browsers like Galeon have copied this
>      behaviour and now also  fetches  .ico  files  and  use  them  for  site
>      logotypes.
>
> As  each  icon or cursor file may contains multiple images of different
>      dimensions and depth, a conversion may result  in  multiple  PNG  files
>      being  created.  Correspondingly,  multiple  PNG files can be specified
>      when creating an icon/cursor file.

Comment: You answered while i was answering, +1

Answer (score 2):

Install icoutils by executing following in terminal :

```
sudo apt-get install icoutils
```

And then use `icotool`

Execute `man icotool` for manual